# Obtain sold products between a selected date range in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written the following query in my child themes function.php file.

The idea is to retrieve the total number of sales for a product that falls under a specific product tag term.

Currently this works exactly as it needs to.

See below:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
           'terms' => 492,
           'field' => 'id',
      ),
   ),
);
```

I want to now extend this code such that this function only retrieves most sold products under a specific tag **but only for the last 7 days**

Any help is much appreciated.